# Player Can't Go Through Open Doorway

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development, collision

I have an open doorway that I've modeled in blender and put into Unity. The player can go through the doorway, but cannot go back out. The player gets stuck running into an invisible wall. I am using mesh colliders.

I've tried editing the geometry of the mesh and moving the mesh. Nothing has worked.

Video of bug: https://youtu.be/woyuY7LUtNo

Comment: Please show us the colliders

Comment: Due to me using non-convex mesh colliders, there's no visualization in Unity for it as far as I know. However, here is the player collider and blender vertex view for the room:
https://imgur.com/uTQvlhc - blender vertex view
https://imgur.com/OV48Vy1 - player collider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use mesh colliders, use multiple box colliders instead. It looks like a strange mesh collider was generated. Also, check that your player isn't too tall for the doorframe.

Comment: Thank you! Using multiple box colliders seems to work, although it is a bit tedious.